# what is the purpose of an asterisk * when using pip to install python packages

Tags: python, pip, google-colaboratory

My understanding of python is very elementary/general and I am learning stuff as I go.

I recently came across this problem when I was trying to replicate some code:

```
!sudo pip install pytest*
```

I got this error: **"ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'pytest*'"**

I was able to install the required packages when I ran the command without the *

Is there a purpose for the *? Will omitting it cause any problems?

(I am working this program on Google Colab)

Comment: I've never used asterisk with pip install. I don't know what it can be used for but you definitely don't need it to simply install pytest. Just go without it. Maybe it's a typo in the code you're trying to replicate.

Comment: does `pytest` have multiple [sub-]modules?? e.g. `pytest-*` to match (e.g.) `pytest`, `pytest-dev`, `pytest-foo`, etc.

Comment: @AdamSmooch yes, pytest has multiple sub-modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A version matching clause includes the version matching operator `==` and a version identifier.

The specified version identifier must be in the standard format described in the Version scheme, but a trailing .* is permitted on public version identifiers as described below.
Prefix matching may be requested instead of strict comparison, by appending a trailing `.*` to the version identifier in the version matching clause. This means that additional trailing segments will be ignored when determining whether or not a version identifier matches the clause. If the specified version includes only a release segment then trailing components (or the lack thereof) in the release segment is also ignored.

For example, given the version `1.1.post1`, the following clauses would match or not as shown:

```
== 1.1        # Not equal, so 1.1.post1 does not match clause
== 1.1.post1  # Equal, so 1.1.post1 matches clause
== 1.1.*      # Same prefix, so 1.1.post1 matches clause
```

See [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/)